# Add my subversion repository to "corp's" subversion repository keeping history of changes

Tags: svn

I currently have a group subversion repository, which has some years of history in it. Corp has offered to host our subversion from now now on. I would like to know what would be the best way to add/import/merge our repository to Corps repository. I would like to keep the history, but I don't mind if I loose the additional props such as username making the changes as a) they dont map onto Corp's usernames and b) I dont have admin access to their server, and cant add those hooks. Corp's repository already has plenty of stuff in - so revision numbers will no longer tally either - I dont mind that. Its just important not to loose the details of the changes (and obviously the order they were made in). I do obviously have admin access to my repository - but not to Corps repository.

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the target repository is. Is it an empty repo they created for you, or is it repo with existing contents and you want to load yours into a subdirectory?

Comment: Good question - thanks for the opportunity to clarify - its the second one - an existing repo with existing content and I would like to load mine into a sub-directory

Comment: There's a big issue here (which may or may not be important to you).  The process of importing your repository will change all the revision numbers of the original repository data, and also your imported content. If you or the Corp uses revision numbers for any purpose (eg in bug tracking) then this may be a deal breaker.

Comment: BTW, why can't they just create another repository on their server?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it myself but it's possible that **svnrdump** is your only chance:

> In Subversion 1.7, svnrdump joined the set of stock Subversion tools.
>   It offers fairly specialized functionality, essentially as a
>   **network-aware version of the svnadmin dump and svnadmin load commands**
>   which we discuss in depth in the section called “Repository data
>   migration using svnadmin”. svnrdump dump will generate a dump stream
>   from a remote repository, spewing it to standard output; **svnrdump load
>   will read a dump stream from standard input and load it into a remote
>   repository**. Using svnrdump, you can generate incremental dumps just as
>   you might with svnadmin dump. You can even dump a subtree of the
>   repository—something that svnadmin dump cannot do.

If it actually works for you, the procedure would be:

1. Make a proper `svn mv` in the source repo to put everything into the subdirectory.
2. Run `svnrdump dump` on the source subdirectory.
3. Load the previous dump in the target repo.

What can go wrong? Most likely, there's history in both repos that contains common paths. I don't have the faintest idea of what Subversion will do. So do extensive testing and lots of backups :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately it looks like this needs admin access and/or the property change hook: 

> svnrdump: warning: W200007: Target server does not support atomic revision property edits; consider upgrading it to 1.7.
> svnrdump: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
> svnrdump: E175008: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
> svnrdump: E175002: Error setting property 'rdump-lock': 
could not remove a property

Answer (score 1):

`svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` [are your friends](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate). You'll have to ask their admin to run `svnadmin load` for you, though.

Comment: Thanks - but I was looking for something I could do myself without involving admins (busy people!). A bonus would be incremental updates if possible until I get everyone moved over.

Comment: @user859955 - "without involving admins  (busy people!)" - what are they busy with? That's their job! (First wrote "their freaking job", but then thought better of it :) ).

Comment: You might be able to do this with svnsync but you'd need admin intervention for that too. Better just to ask. The problem is usually that developer requests like this get lower admin priority than user requests :-/